# Fit of histogram to Gaussian function seems to be wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, histogram, curve-fitting

How to fit a simple histogram by a Gaussian function? This is wrong, isn't it? Why the curve is not wider?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gaussian(x, mean, amplitude, standard_deviation):
    return amplitude * np.exp( - ((x - mean) / standard_deviation) ** 2)

x = [4.1, 4.5, 4.6, 4.9, 5, 4.7, 5.2, 4.95, 5.65, 4.9, 5.05]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

bin_heights, bin_borders, _ = plt.hist(x, bins='auto', label='histogram')
bin_centers = bin_borders[:-1] + np.diff(bin_borders) / 2
popt, _ = curve_fit(gaussian, bin_centers, bin_heights, p0=[1., 0., 1.])

x_interval_for_fit = np.linspace(bin_borders[0], bin_borders[-1], 10000)
plt.plot(x_interval_for_fit, gaussian(x_interval_for_fit, *popt), label='fit')
plt.legend()

plt.xlim(3, 7)
plt.show()
```

**After advice**
[image]

Is it possible to lengthen the fit for larger length than the histogram range?

Comment: Totally different problem now. I changed the title accordingly.

Comment: Remove the first hist plot, set bins in the second to 5, voila. Or plot the second histogram with bin `auto` to see why the curve looks like this. You covered the gap up by plotting two histograms.

Comment: Is it possible to lengthen the fit?

Comment: `np.linspace(bin_borders[0]-1, bin_borders[-1]+1, 10000)`? Also, 10000 seems rather high. The resolution does not require such a high number of data points.